# How to use Google Cloud Run as a singleton application service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I want to use gcp cloud run as a background service with CPU always allocated with a minimum and maximum of 1 instance running at any given time.

The problem is when I deploy a new revision, the old revision continues to run for some time until it is eventually terminated by cloud run. This time is not configurable. During this period there are 2 revisions running my background service which is what I want to avoid due to my application limitations. I want the old revision to be terminated automatically as soon as the new container is deployed and in the ready stage.

I found that manually deleting the old revision will quickly terminate the container. I could update my deploy script to delete the old revision. But this is undesirable because I cannot revert to the old revision in case of a bug.

Is there a way to tell cloud run to automatically terminate an old revision as soon as the new revision is ready?

Answer (score 1):

Running a service as a singleton is not a good pattern because you can have disruption at any time. Remember that Cloud Run is a serverless service and the platform can stop and restart your container at any time (underlying infrastructure outage, maintenance, relocation,...)

If you run something in background of Cloud Run service, like a scheduler or something like that, you can understand that it's not safe and reliable.

I think your issue come from there: If you have 2 versions running in the same time (on 2 difference instances), you could trigger 2 times the same schedule and duplicate your jobs.

Because Cloud Run is serverless, you don't have the capacity to manage the instance lifecycle. I can only help you to understand the Cloud Run behavior and optimize your design to fit the constraints and your requirements!

Comment: My service is indeed a sort of scheduler that listens to events coming in from an external source on a websocket and queues them to process. It is safe to duplicate tasks occasionally and also tolerates restarts at any time. Because GCP doesn't have a FIFO queue managed service, I have to manually develop this pattern in my application. If I did use Task Queues and find another way to order jobs than an in memory queue, I still need a background process that listens to the websocket and enqueues jobs which brings me back to the original problem of a singleton cloud run service.

Comment: Why do you need a single one websocket to listen the event? You could have several instance in parallel with the websocket deployed on them. The client will be connected to one of them. Why the singleton in that case? But you still have your issue: the connected user on the websocket will continue to communicate with the previous instance when you deploy a new revision. You can do nothing for that., maybe to limit the request time out, to for the client to reconnect more frequently and mitigate the duration with a new revision is deployed.

Comment: Websockets are not great for backend updates I'm realizing. The service I am listening to has a webhook version of this same data which would work better with the serverless quality of cloud run. I will look into that. Thanks for the help.